# Can Perl detect if a floating point number has been implicitly rounded?

Tags: perl, floating-point

When I use the code:

```
(sub {
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    print 0.49999999999999994;
})->();
```

Perl outputs "0.5".

And when I remove one "9" from the number:

```
(sub {
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    print 0.4999999999999994;
})->();
```

It prints 0.499999999999999.

Only when I remove another 9, it actually stores the number precisely.

I know that floating point numbers are a can of worms nobody wants to deal with, but I am curious if there is a way in Perl to "trap" this implicit conversion and die, so that I can use eval to catch this die and let the user know that the number they are trying to pass is not supported by Perl in its' native form(So the user can maybe pass a string or an object instead).

The reason why I need this is to avoid a situations like passing 0.49999999999999994 to be rounded by my function, but the number gets converted to 0.5, and in turn gets rounded to 1 instead of 0. I am not sure how to "intercept" this conversion so that my function "knows" that it did not actually get 0.5 as input, but that the user's input was intercepted.

Without knowing how to intercept this kind of conversion, I cannot trust "round" because I do not know whether it received my input as I sent it, or if that input has been modified(at compile time or runtime, not sure) before the function was called(and in turn, the function has no idea if the input it is operating on is the input the user intended or not and has no means to warn the user).

This is not a Perl unique problem, it happens in JavaScript:

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    /* oops: 1 */
    console.log(Math.round(0.49999999999999999))
})();
```

It happens in Ruby:

```
(Proc.new {
    # oops: 1 
    print (0.49999999999999999.round)
}).call()
```

It happens in PHP:

```
<?php
(call_user_func(function() {
    /* oops: 1 */
    echo round(0.49999999999999999);
}));
?>
```

it even happens in C(which is okay to happen, but my gcc does not warn me that the number has not been stored precisely(when specifying specific floating point literals, they had better be stored exactly, or the compiler should warn you that it decided to turn it into another form(e.g. "Your number x cannot be represented in 64 bit/32 bit floating point form, so I converted it to y." ) so you can see if that's okay or not, in this case it is NOT)):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* oops: 1 */
    printf("%f.\n", round(0.49999999999999999));

    return 0;
}
```

**Summary**:

Is it possible to make Perl show error or warning on implicit conversions of floating numbers, or is this something that Perl5(along with other languages) are incapable of doing at this moment(e.g. The compiler does not go out of its' way to support such warnings/offer a flag to enable such warnings)?

e.g.

> warning: the number 0.49999999999999994 is not representable, it has been converted to 0.5. using bigint might solve this. Consider reducing precision of the number.

Comment: Perhaps investigate `BigNum` or other arbitrary precision package. There is no easy fix with IEEE 754 numbers since the precision is -- floating. You could look at the binary representation of what was passed and what is about to be printed.

Comment: Should I just deprecate the passing of floating numbers for such sensitive functions, and suggest using safer object/string representations that the function can check instead? This seems to make sense but then I have the issue of how to check if the function input was a string or a number(both are scalar and fail ref test). These functions rely on users being aware of floating/double limits and carefully checking their inputs themselves.

Comment: All these languages you are pointing out use exactly the same method to represent floats: IEEE 754. Also, some languages round the representation when you print the number but the number itself is unchanged. The only way to change the behavior is to use a different representation or interpretation of a float.

Comment: Is the general answer then "no, it is not possible to detect if a floating point literal in source code has been implicitly converted."?

Comment: If they can put a man on the moon... Of course, it is possible, but it will be a project. Consider `perl -le 'printf("%.18f\n", 0.49999999999999994-10)'` That prints `-9.500000000000000000` so the small difference is forever lost with IEEE 754 unless you can catch the difference. I think the only short route is to use BigNum or [Math::BigFloat](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigFloat.html) and comparing the full representation of the BigFloat to the internal IEEE 754 representation in strings. That is a start.

Comment: "my gcc does not warn me that the number has not been stored precisely" <- Such warnings would be close to useless. The overwhelming majority of non-integral floating-point literals in code won't be stored precisely. Do you really want to see a message like "WARNING: 0.2 is not exactly representable; converted to 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125" for every single floating-point literal?

Comment: @MarkDickinson ok you have a point, but perhaps these warnings can be suppressed by the compiler but do additional tests such as testing if the result of the converted number "rounds" differently than non converted number. Also, 0.2 is representable; I'd like an example using a common non representable number that cannot be manually rounded to something close that is representable. If 0.2 was not representable, there would be an issue finding a number close to it that works just as good that doesn't look strange.

Comment: All this is fine, but what do you *need*? None of this is useful without a context. If you require precision then just use integers with a separate scaling factor. Floating point values exist only because it is sometimes useful to perform slightly inaccurate computations. If that doesn't work for you then you need an integer or a rational, but remember that there are many irrational numbers like pi and e that your computer can never represent accurately.

Comment: @Borodin i was just curious if this conversion can be caught or not, the answer seems to be "no" at least unless you rebuild Perl to do additional tests on implicit floating point converisons. I don't want more precision, I want to know that if the value is not representable, and if it isnt, warn that it is not representable so that behavior of round does not surprise people unaware of floating point behavior. There is a huge difference between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Dmitry: The internal representation of a floating-point value will almost always have a different value from its string form. Perl will keep an integer value when it can, but as soon as you do, say, a division, you may be left with an accurate result (27/3) or an inaccurate one (2/3). It still comes down to why you're interested in this in the first place. As [**Mark Dickinson** suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551006/can-perl-detect-if-a-floating-point-number-has-been-implicitly-rounded#comment66414658_39551006) there is little point in warning every transgression.

Comment: @Dmitry: An abstract question can only get you a little information, and the answer still depends on what you're trying to do. It seems unlikely that you're worried about literal number in code, so what *are* you dealing with?

Comment: @Borodin I'm dealing with building a Math wrapper that has a round function, but when a user enters 0.49999999999999994, there is no way to let the user know that the number cannot be rounded safely, since the function is suppose to round up if the number is 0.5 or higher, but it can't know if the 0.5 or 0.51 are what the user entered, or what compilation decided to replace user input with, and the user has no idea that their number is not representable because the language does not say anything, in turn it is not obvious what the issue is in long chains of computation.

Comment: @Dmitry: But any system will distinguish between 0.49, 0.50, and 0.51. It is the huge amount of precision that you're asking for that is getting in your way, and it seems unnecessary.

Comment: *"Only when I remove another 9, it actually stores the number precisely"* No. Only when you remove that `9` does the *printed output* equal the input string. Floating point is accurate enough for the vast majority of applications. I think it is far more likely that you need to understand better how to handle floats in your code. 0.49999999999999994 is an accuracy of one in a quadrillion. That's *huge*, it's 100,000 times the population of the earth, and you need to be doing some specialist stuff for it to matter.

Comment: I don't really care about precision, I just wanted to know if the conversion can be trapped or not. Even if I had 50,000 byte float, I would still get a conversion that rounds 0.49... with enough 9s to 0.5 and in turn causes wrong round behavior.

Comment: "Also, 0.2 is representable" . No, it's not! Floats are stored internally in *binary*, and `0.2` is *not* exactly representable in the usual IEEE 754 binary64 format used. It's converted internally to the exact value that I gave in my earlier comment; that wasn't a made-up number. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson okay I stand corrected. Anyway discussion on what how to improve IEEE is outside the scope of the thread. I am only curious if it was possible to enable such warnings or not.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @SinanÜnür I want my math library wrapper to warn the user if their round call will produce an incorrect result due to implicit conversion, but since the conversion cannot be trapped, I cannot protect the user without changing to a non ieee model that lets the round function know what value the user actually entered(eg string or hashmap), since the conversion happens at compile time, and the actual user input to the function is not available to the round function to test whether it is doing the right thing: it simply doesnt have the information, the call cant trap it and correct itself.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, the problem as far as I can see it is the desire to do that. Keep in mind that there are a finite number of numbers that can represented exactly in floating point where as ***ANY*** interval, such as `[0,1]` contains ***uncountably many*** real numbers. Therefore, any reasonable use of your library would cause the user to be drowned in warnings.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps use [BigNum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html):

```
$ perl -Mbignum -le 'print 0.49999999999999994'
0.49999999999999994
$ perl -Mbignum -le 'print 0.49999999999999994+0.1'
0.59999999999999994
$ perl -Mbignum -le 'print 0.49999999999999994-0.1'
0.39999999999999994
$ perl -Mbignum -le 'print 0.49999999999999994+10.1'
10.59999999999999994
```

It transparently extends precision of Perl floating point and ints to extended precision.

Comment: This helps, how does it work internally? It seems to completely change the way "(\d+)[.](\d+)" terminals are processed without recompiling the whole Perl interpretor. Also, doesn't it also reach a point where it does implicit rounding, except its much larger? Unfortunately it still suffers from the problem  that if the user tries to pass the number, it will still round unless the user also uses bignum(not just the perl module), which is not obvious unless we trust the user to read the module documentation(Which fails principle of least astonishment).

Comment: BigInt is a wrapper around the GNU [GMP](https://gmplib.org) library. There are certainly internal differences to how floats are represented; perhaps speed issues; certainly binary interchange issues. The representation textually should be the same.

Comment: @Dmitry: bignum uses the overload::constant hook https://metacpan.org/pod/overload#Overloading-Constants; you can do that yourself too.

Comment: bignum does not appear to address the OP's concern over exact representation of floating-point numbers. `perl -Mbignum -E 'printf "%0.30f\n", 0.2'` still prints `0.200000000000000011102230246252`.

Comment: @DaveSherohman   BigNum is not *infinite* precision; it is *extended* precision. If you want to control how much extended precision you wish to pay for (in terms of speed and storage requirements) you would use [Math::BigFloat](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigFloat.html) and set the desired precision. The example you used suffers its own issues: The `printf %0.30f"` causes a conversion to IEEE 754 floats and that is why you see artifacts. Try: `$ perl -Mbignum -E 'print 0.2*100000000000000000000000000000, "\n"'`

Answer (score 1):

be aware that bignum is 150 times slower than internal and other math solutions, and will typicaly NOT solve your problem (as soon as you need to store your numbers in JSON or databases or whatever, you're back at the same problem again).

Typically, sprintf takes care of prettying your output for you, so you do not have to *see* the ugly imprecision, however, it's still there.

Here is an example which works on my x64 platform which understands how to deal with that imprecision.

This correctly tells you if the 2 numbers you're interested in are the same:

```
sub safe_eq {
  my($var1,$var2)=@_;
  return 1 if($var1==$var2);
  my $dust;
  if($var2==0) { $dust=abs($var1); }
  else { $dust= abs(($var1/$var2)-1); }
  return 0 if($dust>5.32907051820076e-15 ); # dust <= 5.32907051820075e-15 
  return 1;
}
```

You can build on top of this to solve all your problems.

It works by understanding the magnitude of the imprecision in your native numbers, and accommodating it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the question, dealing with floating-point numbers in code is quite the can of worms, precisely because the standard floating-point representation, regardless of the precision employed, is incapable of accurately representing many decimal numbers.  The only 100% reliable way around this is to *not use floating-point numbers*.

The easiest way to apply that is to instead use fixed-point numbers, although that limits precision to a fixed number of decimal places.  e.g., Instead of storing 10.0050, define a convention that all numbers are stored to 4 decimal places and store 100050 instead.

But that doesn't seem likely to satisfy you, based on the minimal explanation you've given for what you're actually trying to accomplish (building a general-purpose math library).  The next option, then, would be to store the number of decimal places as a scaling factor with each value.  So 10.0050 would become an object containing the data `{ value => 100050, scale => 4 }`.

This can then be extended into a more general "rational number" data type by effectively storing each number as a numerator and denominator, thus allowing you to precisely store numbers such as 1/3, which neither base 2 nor base 10 can represent exactly.  This is, incidentally, the approach that I am told Perl 6 has taken.  So, if switching to Perl 6 is an option, then you may find that it all Just Works for you once you do so.

Comment: I don't want to build a general purpose library, but rather I want to make a wrapper for Perl math library to act exactly like JavaScript's Math object. Everything seemed fairly easy until I hit the problem that Perl has no easily accessible "round" function, so I tried writing my own and realized that round simply doesn't have the information to check whether or not it is doing the right thing, because floats like 0.49.... get converted to 0.5 rather than 0.4, thus breaking round's invariant without any way for round to know it. I wanted to know if there are clever ways to let round recover.

Comment: I can't shift to another model without making the Math library no longer have the same interface as the JavaScript Math object. At the same time if I stick to the interface, I have no means to detect if the user input which is 0.4999... has been converted to 0.5. It would not be a problem if I could force this particular function to capture the float input as a string(if it was direct input), so that round could check if it is doing the right thing. However this does not seem possible neither; I have to explicitly force user to pass a string or a non float object as input to protect them.

Comment: If my library ends up being used for something important(not likely but what if), and someone who has no idea how floating points work enters 0.499999.. to be rounded for some reason, my library cannot correct this seemingly trivial conversion: it has no idea that the conversion had occured, nor what the actual user input string was before it was converted to fit into a double.

Comment: Maybe i'm just overthinking it. It is logically impossible to  even try to capture such an input by nature of floating point numbers being a native type with no info of how the actual definition string user typed in looked like. The proper way to handle it is to add a warning to documentation and if I really care enough about it, write a round_safe function that accepts a rich data type as input that is less efficient but does not propagate such errors. And if I am really pedantic about it, I can make round output a warning to use round_safe instead.

Comment: @Dmitry: You can control rounding. Use [Math::BigFloat rounding features...](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigFloat.html#Rounding)

Comment: @dawg do those features require me to use BigFloat, or can I use them to change implicit rounding 0.49999... from 0.5 to 0.4~, or am I misunderstanding it.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use one of those packages or you will get default behavior. Or write your own. Or, use `round` from the POSIX module. Or, use Math::Round from cpan. [Tim Toady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) There is a [cheat sheet](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/perl/) that may help.